ontology : the metaphysical study of the nature of being and existence
From Vocabulary.com, under the definitions of ontology, I read:

ontology: the metaphysical study of the nature of being and existence

What is the difference in meaning, if any, between 'being' and 'existence'?

source? Who is the author, please?

@Mari-LouA It's a dictionary definition and I wondered accidentally if there is any difference.

quoting something without attribution is  not correct and what if users want to see the original text. Is it difficult to cite your source and perhaps supply the link?

You also have to show you understand the separate meanings of "existance" and "being"

If you want more information, you can ask on Philosophy SE. They are likely to have (multiple) specific philosophical meanings which people learning English aren't necessarily qualified to comment upon.

Not really.
The definition is just trying to be extra clear about what ontology is, by using multiple synonyms.

To be clear: they usually mean the same thing in ordinary language, but within ontology itself there might be arguments about subtle differences between the meanings of the terms, or some particular philosopher might choose to use each term to mean something particular.
